# Disable asp.net mvc membership and role table create

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I'm using asp.net mvc. Everytime I run/compile the program it creates membership and role tables. Is there a way to disable or stop this? I'm not using those tables. I created my own tables on login. please advice, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because of the built in membership provider.

In a standard new ASP.NET MVC 3 project choosing "Internet Site" option on creation, the web.config file contains the following parts:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

and

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

and

```
<roleManager enabled="false">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Those may be the reason the tables get created.

Comment: thanks, i changed the enable="false" and autogenerateschema="false", but still no luck.

Comment: If you are not using the provider, you can remove the `<add` sections completely.